# terminal command for Espruino Web IDE

Tags: dock

I installed the Espruino Web IDE on my Ubuntu laptop a year or so ago. I am presently grouping my coding tools together in the Dock using this script

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Programming
GenericName=Programming
Comment=Open-source electronics prototyping platform
Exec="~/ArduinoLatest/Arduino-1.8.13/arduino-1.8.13/arduino"
Icon=~/Bilder/Icons/Clock.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Electronics;
MimeType=text/x-arduino;
Keywords=embedded electronics;electronics;avr;microcontroller;
Actions= ArduinoBeta;UIFlow;M5_Burner;Espruino;;

[Desktop Action ArduinoBeta]
Name=Arduino-Beta
Exec=~/ArduinoLatest/Arduino-2/arduino-ide_2.0.0-beta.5_Linux_64bit/arduino-ide

[Desktop Action UIFlow]
Name=UI Flow
Exec=~~/UIFlowIDE/bin/uiflow-desktop-ide

[Desktop Action M5_Burner]
Name=M5_Burner
Exec=~/UIFlowIDE/M5Burner/bin/electron-m5burner-v2-eletron

[Desktop Action Espruino]
Name=Espruino
Exec=
```

The problem is that although I can search for and find and execute Espruino Web IDE vie the Activities menu and in Dock and "Dash to Dock" I cannot find the actual command used to launch the app. How can I find out what command the Dock is using?

Comment: Your `Exec=` commands (and `Icon=`) are flawed. Replace the `~` (and `~~`?) with the absolute path.

Comment: They are the absolute path in real life, I just didn't want the full paths published on the internet. But the script works perfectly well and I only published it as background. The problem, as I wrote,  is I would like to know the command used by Dock to launch the Espruino Web IDE.

Comment: Do you mean `https://www.espruino.com/ide/` ?

Comment: `firefox https://www.espruino.com/ide/` will do it, or change to any browser that you are using before the web URL. Dock files are just `.desktop` files that have the full command in them. `Exec=/usr/bin/firefox https://www.espruino.com/ide/`  or instead of `Exec=` you can use `URL=https://www.espruino.com/ide/` that will use your default browser to open the link in a `.desktop` file.

Comment: Thanks  `Exec=google-chrome https://www.espruino.com/ide/` works by opening a chrome tab with the IDE and I can use this solution. However when the IDE opens from Dock it seems to be a simple window without other tabs, Url, or other Chrome stuff whereas when I open it with `google-chrome  https://www.espruino.com/ide/` it either opens a new instance of Chrome or if one is already open, opens a new window. `URL=https://www.espruino.com/ide/` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `.desktop` file you should be able to run the Espruino Web IDE with `--app` mode in Chrome.

```
Exec=google-chrome --app="https://www.espruino.com/ide/"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for although I didn't explain myself very well!